# How do I update forked code that I have altered?

Tags: php, wordpress, svn, tortoisesvn

Sometimes we have to alter Wordpress plugins slightly to fit our needs. If an update comes up I would like to still be able to update the plugin and merge it with our changes. What is the best to structure my code so this process is not a catastrophe?  We are using SVN to store our wordpress plugins. And we are using tortoiseSVN as our SVN client.

Specifically, I altered qa-lite to take out voting options.  A newer version of qa-lite came out and I want the new features that it has. Other than downloading the new version and combing through to make the changes by hand, is there, specifically, a better way to do it?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm going to remove the PHP and wordpress tags from this, as it's clearly an SVN question.

Comment: @webarto so point them in the right direction of where they should post this?

Comment: @Erty I stopped to care. I told him politely. For everything else, there is FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @webarto This is absolutely a programming question.  I want to know how to alter a Wordpress plugin properly.  With the intent of causing the least damage to the plugin or using some special technique so that when I go to update the plugin I can incorporate my code into the said plugin successfully (that's the potential SVN part).  Possibly along the lines of an Object Oriented technique, or something like that.

Comment: @Matt why would you remove the php tags from this question? This questions bane of existence relies on me writing PHP to accomplish said task.

Comment: @user974407 read FAQ again please. You can get advice in coding, not how to solve your theoretical problems.

Comment: Well, this belongs here or in programmers.stackexchange... and it's a tough call

Comment: @user974407 I removed the PHP tag because your question is about SVN. The language you're coding with is irrelevant and creates noise for those of us who are looking to help solve PHP problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things that comes to mind right now is to consider public release of the plugin as head and your modified version as a branch. So, you'd keep them separated and perform a merge from head to branch in order to get new features. Manually.

Or create a patch from the diff between head and your changes. Then use the patch over the new public version.

Comment: that's actually perfect, it's exactly how it is suppose to work. I'd give you two upvotes if I could.